# Receive push notification in WP8.1

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8, notifications, windows-phone-8.1, azure-mobile-services

I'm new to Windows Phone development and very new to push notifications.

I'm developing a application for my client which uses the Azure Mobile Services push notification. I read [THIS](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-phone-get-started/) blog and added following code in my `App.xaml` at the top of the `Application_Launching` method.

```
var channel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find("MyPushChannel");
if (channel == null)
{
    channel = new HttpNotificationChannel("MyPushChannel");
    channel.Open();
    channel.BindToShellToast();
}

channel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(async (o, args) =>
{
    var hub = new NotificationHub("<hub name>", "<connection string>");
    await hub.RegisterNativeAsync(args.ChannelUri.ToString());
});
```

For the channel name I'm using Device Token. For hub name and connection string I've to ask my client.

But still I'm confuse that how it will get the notification? What are the next steps to receive the notifications? I want to receive the notifications when the app is running in front and back.

Also, I have to navigate to different-2 screens using these notifications.

Please help me.

**UPDATE:**

1. I have a Azure Mobile Service provided by the client.
2. I have the hub and it's connection string.
3. I wan to receive **raw** push notifications in my Windows Phone 8.1 silverlight app.

**UPDATE**

Created a new demo Windows Mobile 8.1 Silverlight app and tried [THIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202977(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_CreatingaPushClienttoReceiveRawNotifications). It worked perfectly. I'm getting the raw notifications in this demo app.

***Now I want to know how can I connect it with my client's API i.e. Azure Mobile Service / Hub? Or there is no need to setup a connection between the created channel and AMS/Hub?***

In last two days I read a lot on the internet but there is no solution for my problem. Please help me.

Thanks

Kapil

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj679948.aspx

This is what you need to work with Push notifications in your windows phone 8.1 application

Comment: FYI, I'm writing Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app. I want to get the raw notifications. Will https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202977(v=vs.105).aspx this work for me? Let me try this and will get back to you.

Comment: Yes. WP8.1 Silverlight App supports Background tasks. As a suggestion, move away from Silverlight as much as you can. There wont be much support going forward.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. This is my first app, now I'll go with the Universal app. Still I'm not able to integrate the push notifications. My question is how to connect to the Azure Mobile Service and get notifications? Can you please provide me some sample or reference URL..